# How to reset count bar count analytics every week using laravel

Tags: database, laravel-8, laravel-9

any idea how to do reset the data analytics every end of week?

what logic should i use. I am done on resetting the data count every end of the day but my problem is how should i do the week data count resetting should i calculate the day if day is greater than the count of the week? but how? anyone can give idea.

I idea code on laravel

Comment: This is my logic in resetting the data count after end of the day

Comment: Please do not use either the comments or the answer space for providing additional info; edit & update your post instead.